# Image from byte array creating bad image when using Marshalling

Tags: c#, image-processing, marshalling, bitmapdata

I am trying to convert a byte array to an image.
For testing I start with this image:

[image]

I then load it into a byte array:

```
byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes("download.png");
```

I then create new bitmap to 'deposit' this byte array into:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(704, 480, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

n.b. the height and width are the same as the original image.

I then create a BitmapData and lock all pixels to be written:

```
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
```

I then copy the data from the byte array into BitmapData.Scan0:

```
Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, bmpData.Scan0, imageData.Length);
```

I then unlock the pixels:

```
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

I then finally save it to a file:

```
bmp.Save("D:\\test.png");
```

That saved file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry what's the question ? Please edit.

Comment: @AceKing What do you mean what is the question??

Comment: usually, OP contains a question. You asked none of it.

Comment: You copy PNG bytes (which are compressed, encoded pixel data) into pixel bytes. What is your ultimate goal, why are you doing this?

Comment: @CodeCaster I receive images in byte array format from a udp connection. I want to save that byte array into an image, I do not need to test the udp. The result is the same as above

Comment: Then create a bitmap from that byte array, specifying the pixel format, so it gets decoded properly.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think I see what you are saying now.  The issue I had with using memorystream was that on the Raspberry Pi it cause a memory issue (not on the desktop) and I was looking at alternatives to load the byte array (which is an mjpeg) into an image

Comment: @AndrewSimpson If the issue is caused by unclosed streams, you should use a `using` block for the stream, create the image in there, and then hard-clone that image (either using `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy` as above, or by using the `new Bitmap(bitmap)` constructor) before the end of the `using` block.